# android fragment listview shows items partially

Tags: android, listview, layout, height

I have an activity with the associated activity.xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/pattern_background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="false" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        ...

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llComments"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<include
    android:id="@+id/layoutComments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    layout="@layout/widget_comentarios_fragment" >
</include>
```

In the LinearLayout with id llComments I introduce a fragment called CommentsFragment dynamically from the activity with the following code:

```
private Fragment commentsFragment;
private FragmentTransaction ft;
...
llComentarios = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llComments);
...
Bundle args  = new Bundle();
args.putString(Constants.IDMODEL, getId());
commentsFragment = CommentsFragment.newInstance(args);
ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.llComments, commentsFragment).commit();
```

The Fragment associated xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/comments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/indicator_internal_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/indicator_internal_padding" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem I cannot solve is to show in the activity more than one item (in fact I am showing one and a third items) in the list if I do not fix a height for the listview.It should adapt to as many items I add to the list in the fragment through the adapter. I have tried different combinations of heights in the layouts and views, but still does not work. Maybe I am annulating one with other.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After some days I find out the exact problem. I was including a ListView into a ScrollView, and that's clearly not recomended by Android developers. 
You can look for further info here: [Why ListView cannot be used in a ScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776685/why-listview-cannot-be-used-in-a-scrollview)

Anyway, if you want to do it, you can do that with a hack. Take a look at these proposals:
[How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing)

For me that worked. Problem solved.